# user is not defined inside map in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react, but I have good understanding of javascript. I don't understand why below code doesn't work.

Here user should be accessible but, I am getting `user is not defined`.

```
import './App.css';
import faker from 'faker';
import Comment from './components/comment/comment.component';

function App() {
  const users = new Array(10).fill({
    commentTime: 'Today 4:00pm',
    avatar: faker.image.image(),
    comment: faker.lorem.sentence(),
    username: faker.name.firstName(),
  })
  return (
    <div className="ui container comments">
      users.map((user) => (
      <Comment
        username={user.username}
        comment={user.comment}
        commentTime={user.commentTime}
        avatar={user.avatar}
      />));
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
const Comment = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="comment">
      <a href="/" className="avatar">
        <img src={props.avatar} alt="avatar" />
      </a>
      <div className="content">
        <a href="/" className="author">
          {props.username}
        </a>
        <div className="metadata">
          <span className="date">{props.commentDate}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="text">{props.comment}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Comment;
```

When I remove outer  `<div className="ui container comments">` it renders fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed curly brace `{}`.

```
return (
    <div className="ui container comments">
      {users.map((user) => (
        <Comment
          username={user.username}
          comment={user.comment}
          commentTime={user.commentTime}
          avatar={user.avatar}
        />))
      }
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Oh! This is why they said think thrice before posting to stackoverflow, thanks.